# Vue 3 composition API passing HTML button type attribute as PROP Typescript issue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Ok, I've GTS'd this to death and cannot find a solution.  I'm trying to create a Vue button component that accepts a button "type" property, basically 'button' or 'submit', and I get this Typescript error:

I've tried many different solutions to no avail.  Anyone have a solution to this issue?

IDE: VSCode 1.77.2 |
Typescript: 4.8.4 |
Vue 3: ^3.2.47

Here's the component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

defineProps({
    btnType: {
        type: String,
        default: 'submit'
    }
});

</script>

<template>
              
    <button :type="btnType" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 ...">
        <slot />
    </button>
</template>
```

Typescript error on ":type" stating:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"submit" | "button" | "reset" | undefined'.ts(2322)
runtime-dom.d.ts(541, 3): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'ElementAttrs<ButtonHTMLAttributes>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Import types `PropType` and `ButtonHTMLAttributes` and use them in your prop definition

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { PropType, ButtonHTMLAttributes } from 'vue';
defineProps({
  btnType: {
    type: String as PropType<ButtonHTMLAttributes['type']>,
    default: 'submit'
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### It's another Typescript headache

Try updating your `defineProps` call to this:

```
const props = defineProps({
  btnType: {
    type: String as () => "submit" | "button",
    default: 'submit'
  }
});
```

This should tell TypeScript that you will only send it strings that are either "submit" or "button", and not other random strings, that may not be acceptable to the `<button>` tag's `type` attribute.

Comment: Thanks!  Will try that.  Trying to understand Typescript coming from a Java background :)